Remove the variable dependence from the limit of integration
Let's suppose that i have a double integral like this:
$$
\int_c^d \int_a^x f(x,y) \, dy \, dx
$$
Can i apply any transformation, just on the variable y, to vanish with the variable x in the limit ? Like this one:
$$
y' = \dfrac{x-a}{2}y + \dfrac{x+a}{2}\\
$$
so the integral is now written as:
$$
\int_c^d \int_{-1}^1 \left(\dfrac{x-a}{2}\right) \,f(x,y') \, dy \, dx
$$

There are several problems with your answer. First of all, the limits of the variable $y^\prime$ will be $y^\prime=\frac12(xa-a^2+x+a)$ at $x=a$ and similarly, the other limit is wrong. Also, when substituting $f(x,y)$ stays $f(x,y)$, and does not become $f(x,y^\prime)$. You need to put
$$f(x,y)=f\left(x,\frac{y^\prime-\frac{x+a}{2}}{\frac{x-a}{2}}\right)$$
And finally
$$\mathrm dy=\frac{2}{x-a}\,\mathrm dy^\prime$$

With all this in mind, now let us do what you wanted to do. Substitute $y^\prime=\dfrac{y-a}{x-a}$. Then, at $y=a$, you get $y^\prime=0$ and at $y=x$ you get $y^\prime=1$. The inverse of the transformation is $y=a+y^\prime(x-a)$, and the differential is changed as $\mathrm dy=(x-a)\,\mathrm dy^\prime$.
Therefore, the integral becomes
$$\int_c^d\int_0^1f\big(x,a+(x-a)y^\prime\big)\,(x-a)\,\mathrm dy^\prime\,\mathrm dx$$
Hope this helps. :)

A factor $(x-a)$ is missing in front of $\mathrm dy^\prime,\mathrm dx$.
